# How many Research Quest can the Empire take in Stellais?

Tags: stellaris

Is there a limit to the number of Research-Quests the Empire can take in Stellaris?

So far there are two active quests the Empire is researching and one Mundane Quest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found no upper limit to the number of entries in my situation log, research or otherwise. I also have no reason to think that there will be a limit.

Furthermore, I've found that you can research many of these simultaneously.

At the start of each game, you will encounter several alien life forms that will produce research entries in your situation log. These all pause the current society technology. According to @Kexlox, the research points during this time are not actually spent on the alien life form research, but are instead saved to be doled out later in a slow release.

So, you wouldn't lose any research points, but you might get your technology a few months later than you would have otherwise, depending on how close it was to completion.

But, I've noticed that, for some reason, you can research all these life form projects simultaneously. So, waiting until you have a handful all ready and doing them at the same time can minimize the disruption to your research, as compared to doing each one as it pops up. I've researched at least six at the same time before.

I would not be at all surprised if that turns out to be a bug, and is fixed in a patch at some point.

### Update:

I've been playing after the Unity DLC, and the bug mentioned above appears to have been fixed. There's still no limit to the number of entries in the situation log, and you can start several of them at once, but it seems that only one progresses at a time (per research type).

Comment: Nice trick - researching them all at once.

Comment: I doubt it's a bug, otherwise you'd only be able to do one debris investigation at a time.  FWIW you don't lose the research points while doing other research tasks.  Your produced research points are queued up, and then spent when research resumes.  The saved research points are spent in an amount equal to your monthly research rate, so if you normally get 50 points a month, save up 300 during a contact research, for the next 6 months you will research at a rate of 100 points per month (50 base + 50 saved).

Comment: @Kexlox Well that seems completely pointless. Why even pause the research if you just get all the points anyway? Gets more counterintuitive the more I learn about it.

Comment: @DCShannon Well, there is a slight opportunity cost decision involved.  If your tech would be finished in less than double the time of the special project (under 12 months for contact projects) then it does delay the time before you get that research.  But if the project is still pretty far out, they can make up the difference in overtime I guess.  I wouldn't be surprised if the system gets some tweaks, especially to make all of this more transparent.  Paradox games definitely get better with age.

Answer (score 3):

**This is a confirmed bug.**

You are only supposed to do 1 per scientist as it is supposed to tie up the scientist. So this is being limited by your scientist Limit for the most part.

Meeting other species is a one at a time Thing.

Side note: science is not being stored properly.

Note: paradox is blocked at work, as it should be. So if someone would be so Kind to find and add the link :)